# How to paginate queryset for Serializer

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-pagination

I'm retreiving `Category` and its `outfits` list. My problem is there are too many `outfits` belong to a `category`.

```
class CategoryListAPIView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategoryDetailSerializer
    ...

class CategoryDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    outfits = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = (
            ...
            'outfits',
            ...
        )

    def get_outfits(self, obj):  //This is returning 39 items. 
        // Can we paginate this? 
        if obj.outfits is not None:
            return OutfitListSerializer(obj.outfits, many=True).data
        return None
```

Can we paginate it so that user can first see 24 `outfits` and refresh to see the rest of `outfits`?

Comment: i think the simple solution is create api method to get the pagination with filter by category

Comment: Did you mean... `obj.outfits[offset : (offset+page_size)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want simple condition "first 24" and "the rest". You could control it by get parameters.

```
def get_outfits(self, obj):
    show_all = self.request.GET.get('show_all')

    if show_all:
        outfits = obj.outfits.all()
    else:
        outfits = obj.outfits.all()[:24]

    return OutfitListSerializer(outfits, many=True).data
```

Now you can use GET `/categories/` for categories with first 24 outfits and GET `/categories/?show_all=true` for full representation